# Why does a new ASP.NET Core 3.1 project generate bootstrap css of different versions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

Recently I started a **ASP.NET Core-Web-App (MVC) .NET.Core 3.1** project and noticed that the bootstrap stylesheets, that were automatically generated in the folder wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/, have different versions:

- bootstrap.css (v**3**.4.1)
- bootstrap-theme.css (v**3**.4.1)
- bootstrap-grid.css (v**4**.3.1)
- bootstrap-reboot.css (v**4**.3.1)

1. Why are versions 3 and 4 thrown together?
2. Can I just delete the contents of the bootstrap folder and replace
   it with bootstrap 4 or 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, yes you can delete these and just replace the files and their corresponding references with whatever bootstrap version you like.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the case and it doesn't work correctly for you, you can update it manually

Right click on wwwroot => Add => Client Side Library

Type "bootstrap" in the search box

Choose specific files of the version you want and click "Install".